# Downloading multiple CSVs from multiple htmls

Tags: r

I am trying to download multiple CSVs from this website: https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices (it takes awhile to load)

I only want the files starting with dwbfpricesauswin and want to download all of them from 010119 to current date one by one and save them in my downloads folder.

```
mydownload <- function (start_date,end_date) {
  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)  ## convert to Date object
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)  ## convert to Date object
  dates <- as.Date("1970/01/01") + (start_date:end_date)  ## date sequence
  ## a loop to download data
  for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
    string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
    myfile <- paste0("C:\\Users\\andrewc\\Downloads",string_date,".csv")
    string_date <- gsub("-","",string_date)  ## replace "-" with ""
    myurl <- paste("https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesauswin",string_date,".csv")
    download.file(url=myurl,destfile=myfile,quiet=TRUE)
  }
}

mydownload("2019/01/01","2019/08/28")
```

I am new to R so my problem is I'm not sure how to get the date in correct format for the url (010119) and I'm getting spaces in the url which is giving me an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate the date range you want using:

```
s <- seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by="day", length.out=365)
date <- format(s, "%m%d%y")
```

This would generate a sequence of dates beginning on 1st January 2019 until 31 December 2019, in the format `010119`, for example.

One other correction to your current script is this:

```
myurl <- paste0("https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesauswin", string_date, ".csv")
```

The `paste()` function by default will concatenate together the arguments using space as separator.  In this case, you don't want those spaces in your URL, so use `paste0()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That worked howver still not sure why my html is getting spaces between dwbfpricesauswin and .csv?
Error in download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesauswin 01012019 .csv'

Comment: Use `paste0` instead of `paste`.

Comment: So now getting 
1: In download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE) :
  only first element of 'url' argument used
2: In download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE) :
  only first element of 'destfile' argument used

Is this the loop not working?

Comment: Add `print(myurl)` to your loop.  What do the values look like?

Comment: Print doesnt do anything. But I'm not sure what isnt working anymore. No data is being loaded...